# Deriving the confidence interval $P(-\Phi^{-1}_\alpha < X < \Phi^{-1}_\alpha) = 1-2\alpha$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I'm trying to derive the confidence interval for the standard normal distribution.

> Let $P\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$
>
> \begin{align}
> &P(-\Phi^{-1}_\alpha < X < \Phi^{-1}_\alpha)&&&(1)\\
> &P(X < \Phi^{-1}_\alpha) - P(X<-\Phi^{-1}_\alpha) &&P(A<X<B) = P(X<B)-P(X<A) &(2) \\
> &\Phi(\Phi^{-1}_\alpha)) - \Phi(-\Phi^{-1}_\alpha)) &&P(X<A) = \Phi(A) &(3)\\
> &\Phi(\Phi^{-1}_\alpha)) - (1-\Phi(\Phi^{-1}_\alpha))) &&\Phi(-x) = 1-\Phi(x) &(4)\\
> &\alpha-1+\alpha &&f(f^{-1}) = id &(5)\\
> &\color{red}{-1}\times(1-2\alpha) &&&(6)
> \end{align}

As you can see, my method is correct up to a factor of $-1$, but I'm not sure where I went wrong... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $\alpha <0.5$, you get $\phi^{-1}(a) < 0$.

Hence,

$1-2\alpha \ge 0$ so for sure $\alpha \le 0.5$. Then,
$$ P(\phi^{-1}(\alpha) < X < -\phi^{-1}(\alpha)) = 1- \phi(\phi^{-1}(\alpha)) - \phi(\phi^{-1}(\alpha)) = 1-2\alpha $$.

Comment: So how exactly is $\Phi^{-1}$ defined, and how do I correct the derivation?

Comment: So $\Phi^{-1}_\alpha = -z_\alpha$?

Comment: $\Phi_{\alpha} ^{-1} = z_{\alpha}$., where $\Phi_{\alpha} = \int _{-\infty}^{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}dz$.

Comment: I realized $\Phi_\alpha^{-1} = \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha) = z_\alpha$. Statistics has the worst notation for everything...