# $\alpha$ in a normal confidence interval

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definition, normal-distribution

Related to: [Deriving the confidence interval $P(-\Phi^{-1}_\alpha < X < \Phi^{-1}_\alpha) = 1-2\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685377/deriving-the-confidence-interval-p-phi-1-alpha-x-phi-1-alpha)

I'm not sure why, but I'm having some trouble with the definitions here.

> $$P\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$$
>   \begin{align*}
> &\alpha &=&\quad P(X>z_\alpha)&(1)\\
> &P(X>b) &=&\quad 1-P(X<b)&(2)\\
> &P(X<c) &=&\quad \Phi(c)&(3)\\
> &z_d &=&\quad \Phi^{-1}(d)&(4)\\
> &f(f^{-1}) &=&\quad \mathrm{id}&(5)
> \end{align*}
>   \begin{align*}
> &(1) \text{ and }(4) \implies &&\alpha = P(X>\Phi^{-1}(\alpha))&&(6)\\
> &(6) \text{ and }(2) \implies &&\alpha = 1-P(X<\Phi^{-1}(\alpha))&&(7)\\
> &(7) \text{ and }(3) \implies &&\alpha = 1-\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\alpha))&&(8)\\
> &(8) \text{ and }(5) \implies &&\alpha = 1-\alpha&&(9)
> \end{align*}

(9) seems to imply that $\alpha$ is a fixed constant, while (1) claims it's a variable, so why is this result wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to (1), (2) and (3) we have:$$\alpha=P(X>z_{\alpha})=1-P(X<z_{\alpha})=1-\Phi(z_{\alpha})$$ so that: $$1-\alpha=\Phi(z_{\alpha})$$ and consequently: $$\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)=z_{\alpha}$$ This contradicts (4).